# Load a UIViewController and before the view loads on screen launch another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 UIViewControllers (V1, V2, and V3). From V1 I would like to launch V2 but before V2's view shows up on the screen and after V2 is pushed onto window hierarchy I would like to launch V3. If I try to launch V3 from V2's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method I get an error "Attempt to present <> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!" and if I do it from V2's viewDidAppear, it's too late and V2's view is already on the screen.

Please help!

Comment: are you presenting both v2 and v3 animated?

Comment: Yes, both animated and modally. I am able to launch V3 from V1 thru V2 but V2 appears momentarily before V3 show-ups and I would like V2 to not appear at all.

Comment: in V1, try presenting v2 animated:NO, and in V2's viewWillAppear present v3 animated:YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in V1, try presenting v2 animated:NO, and in V2's viewWillAppear present v3 animated:YES